# Make sense of this strace output

Tags: linux, java, tomcat, strace

Can anyone make sense of this `strace` output?

```
[pid 25302] read(34, "}B\311\204\n\250\347$\220\266kRb\304a^^\2504\303k\235\227T\223\16\231\306\277\254\256\306", 32) = 32
```

It's from a Linux system running a Java application via Tomcat.  It's trying to read something, but instead of a filename, it has this odd string.  This is where I believe the application fails, and it is the one part I don't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) system call reads some bytes from an open file. The “odd string” is the bytes that are read by the call. This call attempts to read 32 bytes (third parameter), and succeeds (return value), from file descriptor 34.

To find out what file your application is reading for, look back in the trace for the system call that opens this file descriptor. This could be [`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) (return value), [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) (first argument), [`socket`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket) (return value) or a few others. The file descriptor may also have been returned by [`dup`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) or [`dup2`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) or [`dup3`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup3), in which case you would need to trace back the file descriptor that was duplicated. You can also run `lsof -p 25302` to see what files that process has open at the time you run the `lsof` command, if the process is still running.

Comment: FD 34 only appears in read syscalls, I see no other syscall referencing it, even when not filtering at all.  Perhaps it is opened when Tomcat first starts up?

Comment: I looked in proc and 34 references /dev/urandom.  Why might that be I wonder...